# Finding the decade with largest records, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following db diagram :

[image: Database Diagram for Movies]

I want to find the decade (for example 1990 to 2000) that has the most number of movies.
Actually it only deals with "Movies" table.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: You should include a query on what you have tried.  For instance, a query to get the number of movies in all the decades.

Comment: As a note:  1990 to 2000 is 11 years.  Decades usually have 10 years.  Can you be clearer about what you mean by "decade".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the LEFT function in SQL Server to get the decade from the year. The decade is the first 3 digits of the year. You can group by the decade and then count the number of movies. If you sort, or order, the results by the number of movies - the decade with the largest number of movies will be at the top. For example:

```
select
count(id) as number_of_movies,
left(cast([year] as varchar(4)), 3) + '0s' as decade
from movies
group by left(cast([year] as varchar(4)), 3)
order by number_of_movies desc
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the string approach is to use integer division to get the decade:

```
SELECT [Year]/10*10 as [Decade]
     , COUNT(*) as [CountMovies]
FROM Movies
GROUP BY [Year]/10*10
ORDER BY [CountMovies] DESC
```

This returns all, ordered by the decade(s) with the most movies.  You could add a TOP (1) to only get the top, but then you'd need to consider tiebreaker scenarios to ensure you get deterministic results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(cast([year] as varchar), 1, 3) as Decade,
Count(1) [Count]
from Movies
group by substring(cast([year] as varchar), 1, 3)
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT floor(Year(getdate())/10)*10
        , floor(year('5/11/2004')/10)*10
        , floor(Year('7/23/1689')/10)*10
        , floor(Year('7/09/1989')/10)*10
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite being an old question I found this solution via trying

```
    DATE_PART('decade',(year::date)) AS decade,
    DATE_TRUNC('decade',(year::date)) AS decade_truncated,
```

also works for

```
    DATE_PART('century',(year::date)) AS decade,
    DATE_TRUNC('century',(year::date)) AS decade_truncated,
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am having `year` as a string column. To get the movies grouped by decades,

```
SELECT DISTINCT NUMRANGE(
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(year AS INT)/ 10) * 10 AS INT),
CAST((FLOOR(CAST(year AS INT)/ 10) * 10) + 9 AS INT)
) AS "decades", COUNT(*) AS "movie_count"
FROM movies
WHERE year IS NOT NULL AND year != ''
GROUP BY decades
ORDER BY movie_count DESC;
```

This gives the number of movies in that decade. Hope this one helps someone...