# Query for find the decade with the largest number of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database including the following tables:

```
ACTOR (id, fname, lname, gender)
MOVIE (id, name, year, rank)
DIRECTOR (id, fname, lname)
CAST (a_id, m_id, role)
MOVIE_DIRECTOR (d_id, m_id)
```

Now I want to retrieve the data of the following question.

> A decade is a sequence of 10 consecutive years. For example, 1965, 1966, ..., 1974 is a decade, and so is 1967, 1968, ..., 1976. Find the decade with the largest number of films

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Every movie can be seen to be the beginning of a decade. Then, the decade are all years between this movie's year and the movie's year+10.

Comment: You can find your answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338110/finding-the-decade-with-largest-records-sql-server

Comment: @HeshamGomaa The requirement of that answer solution is different from this one.  He's looking for decades that can start on any year. Not only the year where modulus 10 of the year = 0

Comment: Notice that you should employ a *self join*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the decade with largest records, SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338110/finding-the-decade-with-largest-records-sql-server)

Comment: @Nick, It's not a dup of that post. This one starts the decades for each year. Not every 10 year like that other post. That may sound like a minor difference, but does make it harder to calculate. (i.e. no group by on the truncated date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this by generating the years, joining in the movies, and then aggregating:

```
select y.year as decade_start, y.year + 9 as decade_end,
       count(*) as num_movies
from (select distinct year from movies) y join
     movies m
     on m.year >= y.year and m.year < y.year + 10
group by y.year
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Only the MOVIE table seems to matter here to get that answer.

In MySql 8.x one could use a self-join on a CTE for this.

```
WITH MOV AS
(
   SELECT year as movie_year, COUNT(id) as total_movies
   FROM MOVIE 
   GROUP BY year
)
SELECT
  m1.movie_year as decade_start,
  MAX(m2.movie_year) as decade_end,
  SUM(m2.total_movies) as total_movies
FROM MOV m1
LEFT JOIN MOV m2 ON (m2.movie_year BETWEEN m1.movie_year AND m1.movie_year + 9)
GROUP BY m1.movie_year
ORDER BY SUM(m2.total_movies) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

In MySql 5.x, which doesn't support CTE's, simply replace the MOV's for m1 and m2 by a sub-query with the query from the CTE.

Comment: @JimmyB, My golfcoding instincts agree with you.  Certainly if you turn this is a solution for 5.x.  But I think performance will be better if you only join the years to a decade, instead of joining all movies in a year to a all movies in a decade.  Not sure how a HAVING could help here though?

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora That's cool. Well, I'm guessing that you're still using the ol' MySql 5.x, and had to change from the WITH? Btw, 5.x is lacking a lot of nice SQL stuff compared to the 8.x. I don't have a table with a lot of movies to do a performance comparison. I'd be interesting to learn how all the solutions compare in speed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 5.6.x

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this ?

```
select
  m.year as decade_begin,
  count(rollup.id) as movies_count
from
  MOVIE m,
  MOVIE rollup
where
  rollup.year >= decade_begin and rollup.year < decade_begin+10
group by
  decade_begin
order by
  movies_count;
```

Comment: `distinct` should be removed.

Comment: The only thing still missing is to extract the record(s) with the maximum `movies_count`. Most simple (MySQL) way: `ORDER BY movies_count DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @LostReality I'm using MySQL 5.6.x & can't get what is `rollup` and why it is used for

Comment: 'm' and 'rollup' are just table aliases

Comment: That's basically only an autojoin. m is used to get each line and rollup is used to compute our associated agregated values